# Woocommerce checkout - Add discount with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the Woocommerce checkout page to add a discount in the review your order section, triggered by a change of the innerHTML of an element.

The JavaScript I'm using is:

```
var discount = 0;
function innerHTMLChanged() {
    if (jQuery('#hideDiscount').html() != "oldText") {

        console.log("innerHTML has changed!"); 
        discount = jQuery('#hideDiscount').html();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://example.site/apply-discount.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: jQuery('#hideDiscount').html()
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert( data.message );
        });
    }
}

// fires every half a second
setInterval(innerHTMLChanged, 500);
```

The apply-discount.php file contains:

```
<?php


$discount = $_POST['action'];
$reverseDiscount = $discount * -1;

function woo_add_cart_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Discount', 'woocommerce'), $reverseDiscount );
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woo_add_cart_fee');

?>
```

Chrome console is outputing the following when the code is executed:

```
POST http://example.site/apply-discount.php 500 
(Internal Server Error)
m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:4
m.extend.ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:4
innerHTMLChanged @ (index):357
```

Can anyone advise me on what is causing the Internal Server Error?

Thanks in advance.

Here is a screenshot of the console showing the request header with the param name: "action" and value: "0.00" which is the correct POST data, and the response header showing "Internal Server Error". So the AJAX request is being sent, and the error is with the response PHP..?

[image: Chrome Console screenshot]

Comment: What do the error logs say? For the `action` parameter, instead of passing `html()` try sending `val()`

Comment: The element has no jQuery val(). It is simply a <span> containing some text  who's innerHTML is changed via another JavaScript function.

Comment: And the error log, what does it say?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by 'the error log'. Do you just mean the console output, as above?

Comment: By the error log I was referring to the web server error logs. Depending on whether you are using Apache or Nginx or some other web server, the error would get logged to a file with a description or probably a hint as to what is causing the 500 error

Comment: Thanks Anand. The server is running Apache. I'm familiar with running my own Linux web servers and sites, but the client is using shared cpanel hosting on a provider. Normally I would just SSH in to the server to check out the log files, but it's on a client's shared hosting website. I'm not very familiar with cpanel shared hosting stuff. Please keep an eye on this, and I will look into it and get back to you. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

When using AJAX in Wordpress, you'll need to load WP before you are able to use any global variables and/or functions.

At the top of the PHP file that you are posting to via AJAX, include this line:
`require_once( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/wp-admin/wp-load.php' );`

Now WP is loaded and you can use all of its glorious functions.